# How to mark a question as duplicate on Quora?

Tags: quora

I was looking for an option to mark duplicate a question on Quora but didn't find. Is there any option to mark a question as duplicate?

Comment: [https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-redirect-a-question-on-Quora-and-how-do-I-do-it](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-redirect-a-question-on-Quora-and-how-do-I-do-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, there is. It's called "Merge".

## How to

> Once you've found a question that you think has duplicates, click or
> tap “Merge Questions” in the more menu on that question to get
> started.

## References

- [What's Quora's policy on merging questions? - Quora](http://www.quora.com/Whats-Quoras-policy-on-merging-questions)
- [Introducing Question Merging - The Quora Blog](http://blog.quora.com/Introducing-Question-Merging)